# Logic Apps and Azure Functions Durable Functions doesn't fit well

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I'm facing a strange problem with Azure Logic App and Azure Functions Durable Functions which bother me a lot.

Here's the context: my workflow calls an Azure Function because I want to insert data into a database. Because the process may be long, i'm using Durable Functions (thanks to NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask at version 1.1.0-beta2).
The data are inserted thanks to a XML file which comes from a SFTP server. During the workflow, we create it as a blob in a container of a storage account. After that it calls the Azure Functions.

There are 3 methods in my Azure Function code:
- "Run" (HttpTrigger)
- "RunOrchestrator" (OrchestrationTrigger)
- "DoWork" (ActivityTrigger)

Here's a sample of my code:

HttpStart.cs

```
[FunctionName("InsertDataInDatabase_Start")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")]HttpRequestMessage req,
    [OrchestrationClient]DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    try
    {
        log.Info($"C# Http trigger InsertDataInDatabase_Start processed.");

        // Function input comes from the request content.
        var content = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        ProcessRequest requestData = new ProcessRequest
        {
            Data = content
        };

        log.Info($"Calling orchestrator...");
        string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("InsertDataInDatabase_Orchestrator", requestData);
        log.Info($"End call orchestrator");

        log.Info($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

        var response = starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);

        // I specify a response interval so the Logic App doesn't check the status
        // until after 10 seconds has passed. If work will be longer you can change this 
        // value as needed.
        response.Headers.RetryAfter = new RetryConditionHeaderValue(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error($"Error : {ex.Message}");
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Orchestrator.cs:

```
    [FunctionName("InsertDataInDatabase_Orchestrator")]
    public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("Orchestrator running...");
        try
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>
            {
                await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("InsertDataInDatabase_DoWork", context.GetInput<ProcessRequest>())
            };
            return outputs;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error($"ERROR: {ex.Message}");
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

DoWork.cs:

```
    [FunctionName("InsertDataInDatabase_DoWork")]
    public static async Task<string> DoWork(
        [ActivityTrigger] ProcessRequest requestData,
        TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Http trigger function InsertDataInDatabase_DoWork Processed.");

        // Processing requestData

        return "Operation done.";
    }
```

The ProcessRequest object is a simple class containing a single field (Data which handle the content of an XML file, containing data about objects to insert into database):

```
public class ProcessRequest
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is the following : when I look in the monitor of the first Azure Function, it's indeed called :) But when I look at the Orchestrator monitoring, there's no sign of activity :S
I don't know what's wrong, I suspect the NuGet package because it's in beta and unfortunately there's no update for it at this time.

Any ideas ? Thank you

Comment: How big are your XML files? Durable Functions uses Azure Storage queues to schedule work, which have a message size limit of 64 KB, which in turn restricts what you can pass to an orchestration or activity function. Attempting to pass larger inputs fails silently right now, with no record in the execution history. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/139) tracks something that sounds very similar.

Comment: The XML file have a size of 19,8M but I forgot to say it (I'm going to edit the post for other people) : the XML file is added in a SFTP server. But during the workflow we create a blob in a container of a storage account. After that, we launch the Azure Functions. The "fun fact" is sometimes it's indeed fired but most of the time it's not the case.

Comment: Well, have you tried just inserting the data directly?  Meaning, do you really need all this extra complication? You're probably better off passing the data into the database (Azure SQL?) as quickly as possible rather than worrying about how long a Function will take.

Comment: 1) If it's pass-through, a LA connector to your DB would fit better. If you're transforming data before insert, that's a good Functions use case. 2) Passing the blob's URI to the orchestrator and doing retrieval/[transform]/insert in the activity function shouldn't hit the 64KB limit. But if this problem happens at < 64KB, there's something else going on. If so, would you [filing an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension) and [sharing your function name](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)/time you saw this?